How to preserve the instance of Open AI assistance for the ongoing interaction with the model?
I am trying to preserve the instance of the Assistant and AssistantClient class using session variable (asp.net application) and retrieve it for further conversation with the model.  I believe this will help the assistant to retain its chat history so that model response for the new question would be appropriate.
 public class AIHelper
 {


     AzureOpenAIClient? client;

     public OpenAI.Assistants.Assistant? openai_Assistant;
     public OpenAI.Assistants.AssistantClient? openai_AssistantClient;


  public void EstablishAISession()
    {

        client = new AzureOpenAIClient(apiEndPoint,azureKeyCredentials,azureOpenAIClientOptions)

openai_assistantClient = client.getAssistantClient();
                
openai_assistant = openai_assistantClient.CreateAssistant(modelName)

    }

}

//I do serailization and deserlization using below code
if( _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("AIHelper") == null){
AIHelper aiHelper = new AIHelper();
aiHelper.EstablishAISession();
                _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetString("AIHelper", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(aiHelper));
}
else
{

aiHelper = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AIHelper>(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("AIHelper"));

}

I always get aiHelper.openai_Assistant and openai_AssistantClient value as null after de-serialization.
I was expecting de-serialization helps to use the existing instance of Assistant and AssistantClient class.

You should create the Assistant as singleton in your app. For maintaining the conversation you only need to save the thread id and retrieve the thread using the id to continue the conversation.

Using threadID I could preserve the communication details, however after 3 to 4 prompt model keep asking question than providing answer for the new prompt.  is it because of token limit ? any input would help.  Thanks

Sounds like a token limit, prompt issue, or less likely a truncation strategy issue (if you have set any). Try and set a high token limit and see if that works. You can also use the GetMessages on the AssistantClient instance if you want to check if all your messages exist on that thread.

@Sankaranarayanan Rajkumar Use Response<PageableList<ThreadMessage>> afterRunMessagesResponse     = await client.GetMessagesAsync(thread.Id); IReadOnlyList<ThreadMessage> messages = afterRunMessagesResponse.Value.Data;

To preserve the instance of an OpenAI Assistant using session variables, follow the steps below:

Serialize Only Essential Data ,Restore Context with Chat History and Use Serializable Data Structures

The code below defines a serializable class for storing chat history:
public class SerializableChatContext
{
    public List<string> Messages { get; set; }
    public List<DateTime> Timestamps { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
}


The following code stores the context in a session:

var chatContext = new SerializableChatContext
{
    Messages = new List<string> { "Hello, how can I help you today?" },
    Timestamps = new List<DateTime> { DateTime.UtcNow },
    UserId = "user123"
};
Session["ChatContext"] = chatContext;





The code below lists messages from the thread. I used this link for Azure OpenAI:
Response<PageableList<ThreadMessage>> afterRunMessagesResponse
    = await client.GetMessagesAsync(thread.Id);
IReadOnlyList<ThreadMessage> messages = afterRunMessagesResponse.Value.Data;

foreach (ThreadMessage threadMessage in messages)
{
    Console.Write($"{threadMessage.CreatedAt:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - {threadMessage.Role,10}: ");
    foreach (MessageContent contentItem in threadMessage.ContentItems)
    {
        if (contentItem is MessageTextContent textItem)
        {
            Console.Write(textItem.Text);
        }
        else if (contentItem is MessageImageFileContent imageFileItem)
        {
            Console.Write($"<image from ID: {imageFileItem.FileId}");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}


Output:

For more details, refer to this GitHub repository for the OpenAI Assistants client library for .NET.
